# Cannot login google cloud sql(mysql) from GCE using private ip

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

i cannot access the cloud sql(mysql) using private ip on vpc, then this message show.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.146.15.196' (using password: YES)
```

i have confirmed the following items.

- use unix socket of cloud proxy, i can access and login with the same username and password (check username and password)
- In the user table of the msql database, root is host:% (check mysql allow ip)
- The request is being made using cloud logging (request can arrives)
- Connection test passes https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/how-to/running-connectivity-tests (configuration is correct)
- use private ip of connect with tcp of cloud proxy, then i can login (check connect with tcp, and private ip)
- create another cloud sql instance same region then i can login this instance using private ip. (check region problem)

What's wrong?

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to connect to the instance? (don't post password)

Comment: ok
`mysql -u root -p  --host [private ip]` this cannot access.
`mysql -u root -p -S /cloudsql/[instanceID]` this can access.
`mysql -u root -p --host 127.0.0.1` this can access then i use cloud proxy target incstances ( `./cloud_sql_proxy -ip_address_types=PRIVATE --instances=[instanceID]=tcp:3306` ).

Comment: This is all from a machine that's inside the VPC? Like, from a GCE instance? From the Cloud Console?

Comment: from GCE instance!

Comment: Ah HA! I see you got it resolved by turning off ssl only connections. :) You should answer yourself and then accept the answer so others can find/search for it easier!

Comment: ok thanks. i try it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i was self resolved！

the instance has setting of ssl/tls. i can login then it turn off!